# in matlab delete an entire row if the elements in certain columns equal zero

Tags: matlab

I matlab I have a matrix of 4 columns. I want to delete an entire row if the elements in columns two, three and four all equal zero.

So, I think I need to do something like this but I want to ignore column one:

```
data(all(data==0,2),:) = [];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use logical indexing + `any`

```
data = data(any(data(:,2:4),2),:);
```

Here instead of deleting rows we preserve a row if the conditions is not satisfied for it.

Comment: I like this, this is very elegant. Might be worth clarifying in your answer that this is the _reverse_ approach (i.e. you're not discarding rows where the all-zero test succeeds, instead you're keeping the rows where the all-zero test _fails_).

Answer (score 1):

```
% toy example
>> a = [1,0,0,1; 
        2,0,2,0; 
        3,0,0,0; 
        4,4,0,4; 
        5,0,0,0; 
        6,0,0,0; 
        7,0,7,0; 
        8,0,0,8; 
        9,0,0,0]; 

% solution
>> a(sum ( a(:, 2:4) == 0, 2) == 3, :) = []
a =
   1   0   0   1
   2   0   2   0
   4   4   0   4
   7   0   7   0
   8   0   0   8
```

I.e. if the sum of the number of zeros across columns 2 to 4 equals 3, delete that row.
(i.e. use [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/))

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
a(sum((a(:,2:4)==0)')==3,:)=[]
```